# Why is my test function not activating the user?

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I have a django email verification app that sends email with activation url that contains encoded user pk and a token, then when app recieves the correct data in a url it sets `user.is_active` boolean value to `True`. I've written a test that is supposed to create a user and send a get request with it's encoded pk and a token, but it fails to activate my user even though the url is correct (as you will be able to see below)

**views.py** contains signup function and verification class based view.

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #  ... process form data
            user.save()

            # Verification
            email_subject = 'Activate your followerr account'
            domain = get_current_site(request).domain
            user_id = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))
            link = reverse('activate', kwargs={
                'user_id': user_id,
                'token': token_generator.make_token(user),
            })
            activate_url = 'http://' + domain + link
            email_body = 'Hello ' + user.name + \
                     ' please use this link to verify your account\n' + activate_url
            email = EmailMessage(
                email_subject,
                email_body,
                'noreply@domain.com',
                [user.email],

            )
            email.send()
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})


class VerificationView(View):
    def get(self, request, user_id, token):
        try:
            id = urlsafe_base64_decode(force_text(user_id))
            user = User.objects.get(pk=id)

            if not token_generator.check_token(user, token):
                return HttpResponse('login failed')
            if user.is_active:
                return redirect('login')
            user.is_active = True
            user.save()
            return redirect('login')
        except Exception as ex:
            pass
        return redirect('login')
```

Here in my test I create a new user with post request and check if the email exists, then I grab the token from the only email in the outbox (not the best way to do this I'm sure but it works right now), get the user_id and encoode it for the url and send a get request to the view which should find the user with the user_id, see if token matches the user and set `user.is_active` to `True` and redirect to `login` page, however my `user.is_active` value still remains `False` after all of this is done. Here is the test:

**tests.py**

```
def test_signup_email_confirmation(self):
            response = self.client.post('/signup/', data={'email': 'test1@gmail.com', 
                                                  'name': 'test1', 
                                                  'gender': True,
                                                  'password1': 'test1', 
                                                  'password2': 'test1'}, follow=True)
    self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)

    for i in mail.outbox:
        token = i.body.split(' ')[-1]
        print(i.body) #  <-- the entire email body with the activation url
    token = token[38:-1]
    user = User.objects.get(email='test1@gmail.com')
    user_id = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))

    activation_url = reverse('activate', kwargs={'user_id': user_id, 'token': token})
    activation_url = 'http://testserver' + activation_url
    res = self.client.get(activation_url, follow=True)

    print(activation_url) 
    print(token_generator.check_token(user, token))
    print(res.status_code)
    print(user.is_active)

    self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
    self.assertRedirects(response, '/login/')
```

I've already tried using `activation_url` without the `'http://testserver'` part.

Results of the print statements are here:

```
Hello test1 please use this link to verify your account
http://testserver/activate/Mg/ad1ap1-887a3ff4466d2e1d098603ddad24355e/
http://testserver/activate/Mg/ad1ap1-887a3ff4466d2e1d098603ddad24355e/
200
True
False
```

As you can see the url's match but `is_active` value remains `False`.

Comment: Its possible there is some exception happening in your VerificationView, but there is only `pass` in the exception. Try printing out the exception (with print(ex)) to see why the code isnt getting to the step where it makes the user verified.

Comment: Doesn't look like there's an exepton for I am getting nothing in my console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the `user` object in your test class was loaded from the database when `is_active` was `False`. When the view sets `is_active=True` and saves the user, the test method has no way of knowing that the instance has modified.

So, now the `user` instance in the test method still has old value.

If you want to test the modified fields, you must ask Django to refresh the object after saving:

```
user.refresh_from_db()
print(user.is_active)
```

Comment: It actually helped, thank you very much for the information, where can I read more this kind of stuff about testing?

Comment: @SLDem Hi, my explanation of this problem was wrong. I've now amended the answer with the correct information. It is not specifically related to testing. It is just how Python (or rather any other programming language) works.